# Wiped data from MIUI Recovery and now stuck on recovery

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, miui

I'm really new to custom ROM and I wanted to install ArrowOS, BUT when I installed TWRP, it didn't boot into it. Instead, when I press the volume up button and the power button at the same time, it started this "main menu" and under it said MIUI Recovery 5.0.

Then I saw some tutorials and I thought I had to press Wipe Data, then I wiped all data, and now I have no ROM, only this Main Menu and fastboot.

When I boot into fastboot, adb doesn't detect my device. But when I use the Main menu, then it does detect the device, but it says it's unauthorized.

Please help me, I don't know what to do.

Comment: As stated in quite a few other answers fastboot mode is fastboot mode and not adb mode. For fastboot mode you need fastboot binary and drivers.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Sorry, we discourage off-channel communication because it doesn't leave a trail for potential answerers on here. While new users are prevented to embed images here (due to potential abuse), you can still upload them somewhere else and link them on the comment, then the community can help embed them to your post.

Comment: go to the page wherever you found ArrowOS and read the instructions. ask questions in proper support thread/channel

Answer (score 1):

Wipe Data from MI-Recovery Main Menu does not erase ROM, it is only formatting userdata and cache partitions same as factory reset.

Comment: I think did erase ROM because when i boot into the Device it says "Redmi" and the only things i can access are MI-Recovery Main Menu and fastboot

Comment: and i just found out that nothing detects my phone when i am in fastboot